# NHibernate Session changes not being persisted to database

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, persistence

This issue is very weird as it works in many other places in our data manager. For some reason any new code written as below does not throw an error, yet it does not get updated in the database. The session in system memory looks correct, but no changes are enacted when the `.Commit()` is called.

```
 using (var scope = new UnitOfWorkScope())
     {
         InsuranceCertificate cert = _certificateRepository.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == certId);

         cert.Status = new Enumeration<CertificateStatus>(CertificateStatus.Rejected);
         cert.RejectedDate = DateTime.Now;
         cert.RejectedReason = reason;

         _certificateRepository.Add(cert);

         scope.Commit();
         scope.Complete();
     }
```

We are using Fluent Nhibernate and Castle Windsor, if that matters. Again, previous code similar to above works as expected, but any new code does not.

Since we are using the session directly, I have found little help on this topic. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

> log4net logs saying the following: 2012-01-24 11:39:13,475 [37] DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener [(null)] <(null)> - persistent instance of: IDOI.Certificate.Domain.Model.Policy.InsuranceCertificate 2012-01-24 11:39:13,475 [37] DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener [(null)] <(null)> - ignoring persistent instance 2012-01-24 11:39:13,475 [37] DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener [(null)] <(null)> - object already associated with session: [IDOI.Certificate.Domain.Model.Policy.InsuranceCertificate#5]

Comment: What is your `FlushMode` set to?

Comment: Unknown. It is all set up via our Global.asax.cs file. I would assume whatever the default is.

Comment: After doing some digging, it is set to Auto.

Comment: please share your UnitOfWorkScope class code

Comment: The UnitOfWork is from NCommon.Data. We do not have the source code for it.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you are attempting to get an entity out of the repository, change it, and then  add it back in. I am not sure about your repository implementation but given the debug trace in the comments, the session things its already been added to the session - at this point it would be an update rather than an insert that is required.

Try:

```
     using (var scope = new UnitOfWorkScope())
        {
            InsuranceCertificate cert = _certificateRepository.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == certId);

            cert.Status = new Enumeration<CertificateStatus>(CertificateStatus.Rejected);
            cert.RejectedDate = DateTime.Now;
            cert.RejectedReason = reason;

            scope.Commit();
            scope.Complete();
        }
```

Comment: I think the `commit` does it automatically. Doesn't it?

Comment: Thats unknown - nhibernate doesnt have a "unitofworkscope" object so its something he has implemented himself. I will say that a session.commit doesnt necessarily persist right away.

Comment: My understanding, as limited as it is, is that the scope.commit() does all of the session flushing. As I said in the earlier entry, this has been working, and for most of our methods, it still does.

Comment: log4net logs saying the following: 

2012-01-24 11:39:13,475 [37] DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener [(null)] &lt;(null)&gt; - persistent instance of: IDOI.Certificate.Domain.Model.Policy.InsuranceCertificate
2012-01-24 11:39:13,475 [37] DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener [(null)] &lt;(null)&gt; - ignoring persistent instance
2012-01-24 11:39:13,475 [37] DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener [(null)] &lt;(null)&gt; - object already associated with session: [IDOI.Certificate.Domain.Model.Policy.InsuranceCertificate#5]

Comment: I have modified my answer to take into account the debug trace - you should add that to the original question.

Comment: I can see your point about the session seeing the entity in session, but that would be the point in this case: it is an update by that nature. When using the repositories we have, as they are laid out, there is only Add / delete functionality. Mu impression is that the session under the repo would decide to update or insert new. That is my understanding.

Comment: Try removing the "repo.Add" part - just let the session do the update on its own. You shouldnt need to add it back in, you should be able to just get it out of the repo, change it, and commit. I have, again, modified my answer.

Comment: No change persisted. I am going to try and isolate where the issue is, and see if it sheds any light.

Comment: Well, I did figure out, generally, the reason for my persistence issue. We had a custom method decorator that was referencing a repo directly. I am not sure esactly what the fix will be, but I have a work around! Thanks to all!